# Need Driver for Techwell TW6805A or another Multichannel Capture-Card

Tags: video, capture

I am building a video-mix-server and need a Capture-Card, that captures video in 25FPS at PAL-Resolution from Analog Input devices (min. 4 ones)

I found some cards with the Techwell TW6805A chipset, that are effordable.
(For example [this card](http://www.amazon.de/Techwell-TW6805A-Quality-Video%C3%BCberwachungskarte-Zubeh%C3%B6r/dp/B003KEV20A/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=GCPO0HN62IB&coliid=I2G7WDL08JJXLR))

Is there any Linux-Driver there, that allows me to use all Channels, the card supports?

Or is there any other card, that is Linux Compatible, under 500€ and supports a minimum of 4 Channels at 25 Frames per Second each in full PAL resulution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the TW68v2 code from gitorious: http://gitorious.org/tw68/tw68-v2

This works for our multi channel card that has eight Tw6805 ICs, there is a little issue at the moment for us, the video from some channels 'ghosts' onto some of the other channels, but I'm trying to work this out at the moment. I don't know if we are unlucky, have a faulty card, have a ground loop or something else... we've tried many things to fix this.

Choose a card that has as many TW68xx ICs as you want channels of capture, that way you can use one IC per camera and get 25/30fps from each channel.